# AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'reset_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am very new to pandas and trying to use `groupby`. I have a df with multiple columns.

- I want to groupby a particular column and then sort each group based on a different column.
- I want to groupby `col1` and then sort each group by `col5` and then do `reset_index` to get all rows of the dataframe.
- I get the following error 
  `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'reset_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`.

My input dataframe:

```
col1 |  col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
=================================
A    |   A1   | A2   | A3   | DATE1
A    |   B1   | B2   | B3   | DATE2
```

My code:

```
df.sort_values(['col5'],ascending=False).groupby('col1').reset_index()
```

Comment: What is your `groupby` code?

Comment: Provide sample output

Comment: @jezrael: I have provided the sample code.

Answer (score 6):

For `groupby` need some aggregation function(s), like `mean`, `sum`, `max`:

```
df.sort_values(['col5'],ascending=False).groupby('col1').mean().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df.sort_values(['col5'],ascending=False).groupby('col1', as_index=False).mean()
```

Comment: This reduces the shape of my dataframe from (124,14) to (9,6). I want all the 124 rows. Can you please help?

Comment: Sorry this is not an answer in the light of the code the OP posted. They're doing a sort, not summary functions. And they want all the df rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below code, I had a similar issue.

```
grouped=data.groupby(['Colname'])
grouped.apply(lambda _df: _df.sort_values(by=['col_to_be_sorted']))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
grouped = df.sort_values(['col5'],ascending=False).groupby('col1',as_index = False).apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop = True))
grouped.reset_index().drop(['level_0','level_1'],axis = 1)
```

Refer to this stackoverflow link for clear explanation with an example
[How to reset a DataFrame's indexes for all groups in one step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407798/how-to-reset-a-dataframes-indexes-for-all-groups-in-one-step/54801780#54801780)