# Pandas count NAs with a groupby for all columns

Tags: python, pandas

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465023/attributeerror-cannot-access-callable-attribute-reset-index-of-dataframegrou) shows how to count NAs in a dataframe for a particular column C.  How do I count NAs for all columns (that aren't the groupby column)?

Here is some test code that doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2], 
                   'b':[1,np.nan,2,np.nan],
                   'c':[1,np.nan,2,3]})

# result = df.groupby('a').isna().sum()
# AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'isna' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

# result = df.groupby('a').transform('isna').sum()
# AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'isna' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

result = df.isna().groupby('a').sum()
print(result)
# result:
#          b    c
# a
# False  2.0  1.0

result = df.groupby('a').apply(lambda _df: df.isna().sum())
print(result)
# result:
#    a  b  c
# a
# 1  0  2  1
# 2  0  2  1
```

Desired output:

```
     b    c
a
1    1    1
2    1    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always best to avoid `groupby.apply` in favor of the basic functions which are cythonized, as this scales better with many groups. This will lead to a great increase in performance. In this case first check `isnull()` on the entire `DataFrame` then `groupby` + `sum`.

```
df[df.columns.difference(['a'])].isnull().groupby(df.a).sum().astype(int)
#   b  c
#a      
#1  1  1
#2  1  0
```

---

To illustrate the performance gain:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 50000
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [*range(N//2)]*2,
                   'b': np.random.choice([1, np.nan], N),
                   'c': np.random.choice([1, np.nan], N)})

%timeit df[df.columns.difference(['a'])].isnull().groupby(df.a).sum().astype(int)
#7.89 ms ± 187 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.groupby('a')[['b', 'c']].apply(lambda x: x.isna().sum())
#9.47 s ± 111 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply` with `isna` and `sum`. Plus we select the correct columns, so we don't get the unnecessary `a` column:

**Note**: `apply` can be slow, it's recommended to use one of the vectorized solutions, see the answers of [`WenYoBen`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57995994/9081267), [`Anky`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57996145/9081267) or [`ALollz`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57996118/9081267)

```
df.groupby('a')[['b', 'c']].apply(lambda x: x.isna().sum())
```

**Output**

```
   b  c
a      
1  1  1
2  1  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question has the answer (You mistyped `_df` as `df`):

```
result = df.groupby('a')['b', 'c'].apply(lambda _df: _df.isna().sum())
result
   b  c
a      
1  1  1
2  1  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be `set_index()` on `a` and groupby on the index and sum:

```
df.set_index('a').isna().groupby(level=0).sum()*1
```

Or:

```
df.set_index('a').isna().groupby(level=0).sum().astype(int)
```

Or without groupby courtesy @WenYoBen:

```
df.set_index('a').isna().sum(level=0).astype(int)
```

---

```
   b  c
a      
1  1  1
2  1  0
```

Comment: `df.set_index('a').isna().sum(level=0).astype(int)`

Answer (score 1):

I will do `count` then sub with `value_counts`, the reason why I did not using `apply` , cause it is usually has bad performance

```
df.groupby('a')[['b','c']].count().rsub(df.a.value_counts(dropna=False),axis=0)
Out[78]: 
   b  c
1  1  1
2  1  0
```

---

Alternative

```
df.isna().drop('a',1).astype(int).groupby(df['a']).sum()
Out[83]: 
   b  c
a      
1  1  1
2  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `drop` the column after using `apply`.

```
df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x.isna().sum()).drop('a',1)
```

Output:

```
    b   c
a       
1   1   1
2   1   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another dirty work:

```
df.set_index('a').isna().astype(int).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Output:

```
    b   c
a       
1   1   1
2   1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own aggregation function as follows:

```
df.groupby('a').agg(lambda x: x.isna().sum())
```

which results in

```
     b    c
a          
1  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  0.0
```