# Groupby follow by series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
df.Last_3mth_Avg.isnull().groupby([df['ShopID'],df['ProductID']]).sum().astype(int).reset_index(name='count')
```

The code above help me to see the number of null values by shopid and productid. Question is `df.Last_3mth_Avg.isnull()` becomes a series, how a `groupby([df['ShopID'],df['ProductID']])` can be used afterwards?

I use the solution from:
[Pandas count null values in a groupby function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321455/pandas-count-null-values-in-a-groupby-function)

Comment: [pd.Series.Groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html)  .See docs.

Comment: To add some context, the above construction allows you to make use of `Series.GroupBy.sum` which is implemented in cython and is extremely fast. This gets asked a lot, so you can see some simple timing difference here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995951/pandas-count-nas-with-a-groupby-for-all-columns/57996118#57996118

Answer (score 0):

You should filter your df first:

```
df[df.Last_3mth_Avg.isnull()].groupby(['ShopID','ProductID']).agg('count')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to use groupby:

The common way is to use on the dataframe so you just mention the column names in the `by=` parameter

The second way is you apply on a series but use equal sized series in the `by=` parameter. This is rarely used and helps when you want to do convertions on a specific column and use groupby in the same line
So, the above code line should work